# Cannot use tab-completion for VS Code in zsh on Ubuntu 23.04 - tries to evaluate instead of suggesting paths to files

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, zsh, tab-completion

I am using VS Code as my primary text editor, which I can launch from a terminal with `code`.

With bash, I can use `code <tab>` in order to generate a list of directories & files for opening a new VS Code session in. However, when I am trying on my fresh install of Ubuntu, I am getting an error as if zsh is trying to run some other command:

```
(eval):1: command not found: _code.dpkg-new
```

Example case, from the desktop, where there exists a directory named Projects:

IN:

```
<usr>-<machine>% code Pro<tab>
```

OUT:

```
<usr>-<machine>% code Pro<tab>(eval):1: command not found: _code.dpkg-new
```

Using other commands results in the expected behavior: the Projects directory is auto-completed. e.g.,:

IN:

```
<usr>-<machine>% cd Pro<tab>
```

OUT:

```
<usr>-<machine>% cd Projects/
```

My `.zshrc` is completely commented out but it seems to make no difference even after starting a new terminal session.

A commentor suggested this was a duplicate of [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882300/how-can-i-get-bash-and-zsh-completions-for-vs-code-on-the-commandline), but the suggested solution in that post did not help, rather yielding a different error when I tried (as commented in that post and below).

I am not using Oh-my-zsh.

I am new to Ubuntu. I have a fresh install from yesterday.

IN:

```
lsb_release -a
```

OUT:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar
```

I have looked at these sites, but the advice does not help:

- https://superuser.com/questions/958903/zsh-autocomplete-filenames-if-no-other-completion-available
- [zsh tab completion bug on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146306/zsh-tab-completion-bug-on-ubuntu)
- [Zsh completion need to hit <TAB> twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45449634/zsh-completion-need-to-hit-tab-twice)
- [https://superuser.com/questions/394824/how-can-zsh-be-configured-to-autocomplete-directory-name-with-camelcase-matching#:~:text=If%20you%20hit%20TAB%20again%20%28depending%20on%20your,filename%20to%20guide%20the%20completer.%20%E2%80%93%20Phil%20Hord](https://superuser.com/questions/394824/how-can-zsh-be-configured-to-autocomplete-directory-name-with-camelcase-matching#:%7E:text=If%20you%20hit%20TAB%20again%20%28depending%20on%20your,filename%20to%20guide%20the%20completer.%20%E2%80%93%20Phil%20Hord)
- [How can I get Bash and Zsh completions for VS Code on the commandline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882300/how-can-i-get-bash-and-zsh-completions-for-vs-code-on-the-commandline)
- And a few others whose links have been buried in the tons of open tabs I have

I will accept an answer that helps me use zsh with the `code` command to auto-complete paths using tab as I can already do in bash on this Ubuntu machine (and I'm fairly certain I can already do with zsh on a Macbook, but I have not verified tonight).

**Resolution:**

I originally installed VS code using `apt` following [this tutorial](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-vscode-ubuntu). Uninstalling then reinstalling with `snap` using the same tutorial resolved the issue. Not sure what is wrong with the `apt` installation, but I'm glad the issue is resolved now. Thanks for your posts at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882300/how-can-i-get-bash-and-zsh-completions-for-vs-code-on-the-commandline), @starball.

Comment: dup of [How can I get Bash and Zsh completions for VS Code on the commandline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882300/how-can-i-get-bash-and-zsh-completions-for-vs-code-on-the-commandline) ?

Comment: @starball: thanks for the call out! I missed that post, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem.

In Ubuntu 23.04, adding `source /usr/share/code/resources/completions/zsh/_code` to the top of my `.zshrc` file does not fix auto-complete with `code` from the command line. From zsh, when I try to run `code <tab to start auto-complete>` I get the error: `_arguments:comparearguments:327: can only be called from completion function`.